# How to transfer files to another server using RTMP protocol?

Tags: php

I used to transfer temporarily-direct-linked files to my server because my internet speed is not as much as my server. The method I'm using (`fread`) only works with http protocol. But I can not even get connected to files accessible using RTMP protocol using `fopen`. Could you tell me what can I do to get around this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) - this can be compiled with librtmp support. Not sure if it's supported within the PHP curl extension, but you could simply use curl as a separate process.

Comment: I installed curl but it says that "Unable to find the wrapper "rtmp" "